# Android & fb connect : how to get the right HashKey?

Tags: android, facebook-javascript-sdk, phonegap-plugins, facebook-android-sdk, cordova-plugins

I get the facebook error 
`the key myAppKey dons't match any allowed key`
It actually matches the only allowed key in the facebook app parameters.

Where does the problem come from ?
(I am using Cordova Facebook plugin)

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the hash key and add the key in your facebook app settings. Read this -

[Facebook Android SDK Getting Started](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/)

If you are using latest cordova plugin and then directly started from Step 4 - Run the Sample, it shows the steps to generate hash key and then the step 5 for configuring your Facebook app.